# C# library to resize an image with "content aware scaling" algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, image-manipulation

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIFCV2spKtg

Is there any library that uses "content aware scaling" algorithm to resize images? Or built-in methods to achieve it?

It is the same used on Photoshop CS4+...

Comment: It is called "content aware scaling".

Comment: see this thread on content-aware scaling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530449/how-does-content-aware-fill-work/3650650#3650650

Comment: The http://imageresizing.net library has a plugin for seam carving that is based on CAIR, the fastest algorithm/library for it that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mike Swanson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mswanson/) has done many useful graphics related tools including a C# implementation of content aware scaling called [SEAMonster](https://web.archive.org/web/20180116092847/http://seamonster.codeplex.com:80/)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using photoshop. maybe some of the APIs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this [liquid rescale](http://liblqr.wikidot.com/) or [resynthesizer](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/resynthesizer) in the same way gd-sharp provides a C# interface to the externed gd library. Then us that semi-iteratively.